# how to add payment method to magento report

Tags: magento-1.8, reports

i have followed 
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/comment-page-1/#comment-429849
to create costume report for magento 1.8 it work correctly 
now i want to add new column for "Payment Method"

help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php** -> **protected function _prepareCollection()** add this:

```
->join(array('p' => 'sales/order_payment'), 'main_table.entity_id = p.parent_id', array(
    'payment_method' => 'method'
))
```

and in **protected function _prepareColumns()** add:

```
$this->addColumn('payment_method', array(
    'header' => $helper->__('Payment Method'),
    'index'  => 'payment_method'
));
```

---

For shipping cost add this:

```
$this->addColumn('base_shipping_amount', array(
    'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Amount (Base)'),
    'index'  => 'base_shipping_amount'
));
// or/and this:
$this->addColumn('shipping_amount', array(
    'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Amount (Purchased)'),
    'index'  => 'shipping_amount'
));
```

Comment: can you help me adding shipping cost colomn

Comment: See my answer (I edited it) and please accept it if it's useful.

Comment: hi very thank you Michael 
how can i accept you great answer

and how can i add "price for one product buyed " column
   
i have already added it but some products with different size and different cost give  "0"

Comment: Please paste your code.

Comment: i have edited the post

Comment: can i mail you 
so i can send Grid.php file to you ?

Comment: can you please tell me how can i add also 'billing name'

Answer (score 0):

**Enabling Payment Method Filter**

If you need to filter the report based on Payment Method, use the following code in **protected function _prepareColumns()** method in **Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php**

```
$this->addColumn('payment_method', array(
            'header' => $helper->__('Payment Method'),
            'index'  => 'payment_method',
            'filter_index' => 'method'
        ));
```

Comment: can you please tell me how can i add also 'billing name'