# how to add shipping cost magento report?

Tags: magento-1.8, reports

i have followed
 http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-a-custom-grid-from-scratch/comment-page-1/#comment-429849
for creating report for magento 1.8 it was OK
now i want to add new column for "Shipping Cost"

please hrlp

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this in your previous question too ([how to add payment method to magento report](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58564/how-to-add-payment-method-to-magento-report/)).
In **Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php -> protected function _prepareColumns()** add:

```
$this->addColumn('base_shipping_amount', array(
    'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Amount (Base)'),
    'index'  => 'base_shipping_amount'
));
// or/and this:
$this->addColumn('shipping_amount', array(
    'header' => $helper->__('Shipping Amount (Purchased)'),
    'index'  => 'shipping_amount'
));
```

Please accept my answers if there are helpful.

Comment: Please see here - http://magento.stackexchange.com/tour ("To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in." and "Click the large up arrow to the left of a post, or the small up arrow to the left of a comment.").

Comment: Done i have accepted it 
you are great :) 
i have commented on the other question 
Can you help me 
"
hi very thank you Michael how can i accept you great answer and how can i add "price for one product buyed " column i have already added it but some products with different size and different cost give "0"

image show the error
http://s7.postimg.org/nrj8yafyz/Capture.png

Comment: Please paste your code.